# Can you make a sticker app have sounds?

Tags: ios, imessage

When you make an iMessage sticker application is it possible to have it make a sound once its tapped on? Example: You sent someone a sticker and they tap on it and it makes a noise. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can with iMessage. As per Apple documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/imessage/).

**iMessage Application**

> iMessage app. Your app can include stickers, text, video and audio.
>   You can also use code to add functionality such as Apple Pay and
>   in-app purchase. Choose to list your app in the Stickers category or
>   another relevant category on the App Store for iMessage.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: yes but the sounds need to be 'packed' in video files. This way you can play them by a single tap.

As of Oct 2023, iOS 17 the `MSMessageTemplateLayout.mediaFileURL` supports only local video files. You can a video file either in:

1. `conversation.insert(message) and MSMessage/MSMessageTemplateLayout`. Such message can contain caption, caption, your app icon and other metadata along with the video file. When tapped you'll probably need to open it full screen in order to enable sound.
2. or as attachment via `conversation.insertAttachment(url:)`.
   The simple attachment allows you to play a video/sound by simply tapping on it. This is the preferred way if you want to show an emoji with sound. There will be a 'play' icon.