# IOS message stickers with sound

Tags: ios, ios-stickers

I have created several iOS messages sticker pack apps. I’ve told customers that you can only send images, not sound, since the format for stickers must either be apng or gif. Then I saw there are apps like “Emoji Tones” that have videos with sound IN Sticker Packs! How is this possible?

This particular app comes with both a sticker pack and an iOS app. Presumably the video sticker is stored in the app and that’s how they’re able to share these video stickers. I need to create one of these apps but don’t know where to begin.

Anyone out there know how to create an iOS Messages app with video stickers or stickers with sounds like this “Emoji Tones”?

[image: Emoji Tones]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As apple reference:
https://developer.apple.com/imessage/

And a reference from staxkoverflow is:
https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41093651/can-you-make-a-sticker-app-have-sounds&ved=2ahUKEwiRkfW86rroAhWJiOAKHXu0A4AQFjABegQIBhAB&usg=AOvVaw2frwR6f6K6fT9wbV9tiqvD

You can start from here...

Comment: Ahh, yes. "Standalone iMessage App
Your app can include stickers, text, video, and audio."

Comment: Yup you can ^_^.